# Trees won't grow in minecraft FTB

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have created a 2x2 spruce tree farm in Feed The Beast and the trees won't grow at all. I have tried giving the saplings bonemeal and other things I found on the internet, but they still will not grow. Here's a picture of my tree farm:

[image: Image Description]

Comment: Seems like you have mods, try to remove mods and try again, as mods can cause problems.

Comment: Spruce spawn leaves close to the ground and as crazy as this seems the chest and such could be causing you the issues. As a test try just moving a block of dirt to an area where you have 3-4 spaces around it clear on all sides and give it a go again.

Comment: @ardaozkal Well it's FTB so there are mods, what did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Minecraft Wiki article about trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Spruce_trees) might be useful. I assume you are trying to grow a Mega Spruce Tree (2 blocks x 2 blocks).

> To grow a 2×2 mega spruce tree variant, there must be no block other than air, wood, leaves or saplings either directly next to or diagonally to the northwest spruce sapling.

You have a block that I don't recognize next to the northwest sapling. This is most likely the problem; try removing that block.

If that doesn't work:

- Do you have enough light? Try using the bonemeal during the daytime.
- Have you tried applying bonemeal more than once? It's only successful sometimes.

Feel free to leave a comment below this post if you're still having problems.

Comment: Thanks! :D I did everything you guys suggested and I got it to work ;)